# upload excel file webapi and angularjs and ajax call

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

i have following code i want to upload excel file and save to server. but this function not working it show me  `500 (Internal Server Error)` what's wrong in my code please help me this any professional i spend 3 hours but not success . i was google but not success simple i want to upload file through angularjs or ajax call

> C# Code not call from AJAX i think this that's why its show error

HTML

```
  <input type="file" id="uploadInput" />
 <button ng-click="SubmitForm()" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>



 AppModel.controller('ImportExcelCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http', function ($scope, $filter, $http) {
        $scope.SubmitForm = function () {
            var element = document.getElementById("uploadInput");
            var file = element.files[0];
            console.log(file.name);
            console.log(file);
            var loFormData = new FormData();
            loFormData.append("filename", file.name);
            loFormData.append("file", file);

            var loAjaxRequest = $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/api/myapi/UploadFileExcel",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: loFormData,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
            });

            loAjaxRequest.done(function (xhr, textStatus) {
                alert(textStatus);
            });
        };
    }]);
```

CS

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFileExcel()
        {
            if (!this.Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            try
            {
                var loProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(Path.GetTempPath());

                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(loProvider);

                string lsFilename = loProvider.FormData.GetValues("filename").First();
                var loFile = loProvider.FileData.First();
                string lsFileContent = File.ReadAllText(loFile.LocalFileName);

                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to see logs of your server. That will give you more hints than people here can.

Comment: its shows 500 internal server error .but cs side function not call

Comment: yes, but you need to see the logs of the server so you see the reason for the 500.